# Rolling Dice loop program in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Rolling Dice program. How do I stop the loop after 10 times?

It needs to return how many times the computer wins, the user wins or tie.

And when the loop terminates how do I print who won overall?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int die1=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int die2=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);

        int comp_wins = 0;
        int user_wins = 0;
        int tie = 0;
        int count = comp_wins + user_wins + tie;

        while (count < 11)
        {
            if (die1 > die2)
            {
                comp_wins++;
                System.out.println ("Computer Wins: " + comp_wins);
            }
            if (die2 > die1)
            {
                user_wins++;
                System.out.println ("User Wins: " + user_wins);
            }
            else
                tie++;
                System.out.println ("Ties: " + tie);
        }       

        System.out.println ("The" + "wins overall!");
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.  At a minimum you are expected to tell us what doesn't work and what you have done to troubleshoot.  Questions of the form "here's my code, debug it for me" are considered off-topic.

Comment: How do I stop the while loop after 10 times (rolls)?

Comment: Count it. At the end of loop increase variable by one so you don't get infinite loop. Starting value should be 0 and checker should be variable < 10

Comment: This would be a good fit for a `for` loop, to replace your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You just need to roll the dice and to increment `count` within the `while` loop, instead of before it.

To display who wins, you can compare `comp_wins` and `computer_wins` within an `if` statement.

---

Updating my answer:
You set the value of die1 and die2 before the `for` loop: this is why the same player wins every time. In effect, you're rolling the dice once, then checking the dice ten times. (Try verifying this for yourself by adding `System.out.println(die1 + " " + die2);` within the `for` loop; this is a useful way of debugging your own code.)

You just need to move the "dice rolls" into the `for` loop:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int MAXSTOPCOUNT = 10;
    int comp_wins = 0;
    int user_wins = 0;
    int tie = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSTOPCOUNT; i++) {
      int die1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
      int die2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);

      if (die1 > die2) {
        comp_wins++;
        System.out.println("Computer Wins: " + comp_wins);
      } else if (die1 < die2) {
        user_wins++;
        System.out.println("User Wins: " + user_wins);
      } else {
        tie++;
        System.out.println("Ties: " + tie);
      }

    }

    if (comp_wins > user_wins)
      System.out.println("The computer wins overall!");
    else
      System.out.println("The user wins overall!");
  }
```